# SVM using Encog in Java for beginners

Tags: java, machine-learning, svm, encog

I am beginner in SVM. Could someone please help me to understand the concepts of SVM using Encog from the very basics?? It will be helpful with sample Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Encog SVM is just a classification or regression model and can be used mostly interchangably with other model types.  I modified the Hello World XOR example to use it, you can see the results below.

This is a decent intro to them:  http://webdoc.nyumc.org/nyumc/files/chibi/user-content/Final.pdf
This is a more basic intro to modeling in general, I wrote it for neural networks, but it applies to SVM as well:  http://www.heatonresearch.com/content/non-mathematical-introduction-using-neural-networks

```
package org.encog.examples.neural.xor;

import org.encog.Encog;
import org.encog.ml.data.MLData;
import org.encog.ml.data.MLDataPair;
import org.encog.ml.data.MLDataSet;
import org.encog.ml.data.basic.BasicMLDataSet;
import org.encog.ml.svm.SVM;
import org.encog.ml.svm.training.SVMTrain;

public class XORHelloWorld {

    /**
     * The input necessary for XOR.
     */
    public static double XOR_INPUT[][] = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 1.0, 0.0 },
            { 0.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 } };

    /**
     * The ideal data necessary for XOR.
     */
    public static double XOR_IDEAL[][] = { { 0.0 }, { 1.0 }, { 1.0 }, { 0.0 } };

    /**
     * The main method.
     * @param args No arguments are used.
     */
    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        // create a SVM for classification, change false to true for regression     
        SVM svm = new SVM(2,false);

        // create training data
        MLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(XOR_INPUT, XOR_IDEAL);

        // train the SVM
        final SVMTrain train = new SVMTrain(svm, trainingSet);
        train.iteration();
        train.finishTraining();

        // test the SVM
        System.out.println("SVM Results:");
        for(MLDataPair pair: trainingSet ) {
            final MLData output = svm.compute(pair.getInput());
            System.out.println(pair.getInput().getData(0) + "," + pair.getInput().getData(1)
                    + ", actual=" + output.getData(0) + ",ideal=" + pair.getIdeal().getData(0));
        }

        Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
    }
}
```